# Button click does not work correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know what i am doing wrong it's a 2D project there are two objects.One has a `RigidBody2D` and `BoxCollider2D` component. Second object only has `BoxCollider2D`. And bottom there is a button when press button `Object1` fall on `Object2` and `Destroy` and `Instantiate` `Object1` again. But when `Object1 Instantiate` then click on button does not work. And error came up like this :

`The object of type Rigidbody2D has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.`

Object 1:

[image]

Object 2:

[image]

Button Click:

[image]

Object 1 Script:

```
public class Object1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Object1 instance;

    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D body;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool hasdropped;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool click;

    [SerializeField]
    private float PointerPos;

    [SerializeField]
    private float BorderX;

    void Awake(){

        if (instance == null) {

            instance = this;
        }

        //take width of screen
        Vector3 gameScreen = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height,0));

        BorderX = gameScreen.x - 0.6f;




        body.isKinematic = true;
        click = true;
        hasdropped = true;


    }



    void FixedUpdate () {

        if (click) {

            Vector3 temp = transform.position;

            PointerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;

            temp.x = Mathf.Clamp(PointerPos,-BorderX,BorderX);

            body.position = temp;

            if(hasdropped){
                return;

            }

        }


    }

    public void ButtonClick(){

        body.isKinematic = false;

    }


}
```

Object 2 Script:

```
public class Object2 : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject BallClone;




    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target){

        Destroy (target.gameObject);

        Instantiate (BallClone,new Vector3(0f,2f,59f),Quaternion.identity);


    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, 2 things. Pls, see if this make sense for you. 1- Instead of destroying, do it on a pool. Reset it. 2- Try to use tag to access the rigidbody instead of public object.

Comment: Are you using instance reference somewhere else?

Comment: @ゴスエン ヘンリ typing enter is no new line, it posts. Kinda annoying actually.

Comment: @fafase haha yeah. Edited :~~

Comment: @ゴスエンヘンリ What do you mean do it on a pool

Comment: You don't destroy the object per se. You deactivate/disable it. You can, for instance, put on it a script with a reset method to a fixed initial position/stat if you want. And instead of instantiate it again, you just activate it again. This way you can track the same object - if it is referenced at some public variable it is practical. Or, if this is not applicable, you can make a tag to find generic tagged objects. Instead of tracking a specific referenced public object, you can track any tagged. Just a try out.

Comment: And just a question, to remove this of the way: the "Object1Prefab" on the Object 2 Script is the prefab or the actual live game object? :O (they have same name, so)

Comment: @ゴスエンヘンリ Can you do that with this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnZ0NaZ2JjcXpsdnc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you referenced the Object1Prefab (the live object, not the prefab) on ClickButton On Click(). (But referencing the prefab will not work at all)

Since you destroy it, you missed the link. (Check it: Select the ClickButton object on the hierarchy, there is the script reference, right? Click the game button once. Now deselect and select ClickButton object on hierarchy again... it is gone.)

Try to make a listener or to put the ButtonClick() method inside the object2 (that you don't destroy):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Object2 : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject BallClone;

    public GameObject mine;


    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target){

        Destroy (target.gameObject);

        mine = Instantiate (BallClone,new Vector3(0f,2f,59f),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;


    }




public void ButtonClick(){
//this is just an example. You might wanna to cache this info for better practice and not call GetComponent all the time
            mine.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().isKinematic = false;
        }




}
```

1- Drag GameObject1Prefab (live object) to the Object2 script on "mine" field. Reference to `public GameObject mine`.

The first click you gonna destroy it, and create a new one and programmatically referencing the new one again on the line:

```
mine = Instantiate (BallClone,new Vector3(0f,2f,59f),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

On the ClickButton Object, you drag the GameObject2, not the 1, on the On Click().

Is this clear? Sorry my english. :~

Comment: thanks for your answer now i understand and last thing what is the best practice to solve this kind of issue

Comment: now it's tricky. Since you destroy and create again, you have to use the GetComponent to reference Rigidbody again. (As far as I know). But since the method is not an update, you can use GetComponent without guilty on mind. It is cool.