# Button onClick does not collide with object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a mobile project and there are two colliders left right and above a cube `RigidBody` which control with mouse. When i press `Button` cube `isKinematic = false` but the problem is when it collide with collider i want to `Instantiate` a new cube and then run same process. I write the code but it's not working. One cube fall and second cube is `Instantiated` it doesn't perform `onClick`.

Cube Script:

```
   public class CubeScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float pos;
    private bool fall;
    private bool exit;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D body;

    void Awake ()
    {

        body.isKinematic = true;

        fall = true;

        exit = true;



    }

    void Update ()
    {

        if (fall) {

            Vector3 temp = transform.position;

            pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition).x;

            temp.x = Mathf.Clamp (pos, -2.73f, 2.73f);

            body.position = temp;

            if (exit) {

                return;  
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Left Collider:

```
    public class LeftCollider : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject cube;

    [SerializeField]
    private BoxCollider2D collide;

   [SerializeField]
   private GameObject CubeClone;

   private Button touchbutton;

    void Awake ()
    {
        collide.isTrigger = true;


        touchbutton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("TouchButton").GetComponent<Button> ();

        touchbutton.onClick.AddListener (() => CubeShoot ());



    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
        cube = Instantiate (CubeClone, new Vector3 (0f, 1.934f, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }

    public void CubeShoot ()
    {
        cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().isKinematic = false;
    }

}
```

Right Collider:

```
  public class RightCollider : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject cube;

    [SerializeField]
    private BoxCollider2D collide;

   [SerializeField]
    private GameObject CubeClone;

    private Button touchbutton;

    void Awake ()
    {
        collide.isTrigger = true;

        touchbutton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("TouchButton").GetComponent<Button> ();

        touchbutton.onClick.AddListener (() => CubeShoot ());


    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
        cube = Instantiate (CubeClone, new Vector3 (0f, 1.934f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public void CubeShoot ()
    {
        cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().isKinematic = false;
    }

}
```

image
[image]

Comment: Your code seems to do what you want it to do, I tried to recreate a small project with your code and it worked well. Only thing I can think about right now is - `CubeClonePrefab`, you sure it is set up is correctly?

Comment: @YuraNudelman what is the problem and `CubeClonePrefab` is the clone of cube that instantiate again collide where is your recreate small project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is kinda similar, but now you have 2 colliders:

[Button click does not work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088939/button-click-does-not-work-correctly/34090323#34090323)

The way I make it to work, based on the actual programming is to make like:

For Colliders (For both - pay attention for the first line, I'm pasting the LeftCollider, the other one should be RightCollider):

```
public class LeftCollider : MonoBehaviour {

    //public GameObject cube;

    [SerializeField]
    private BoxCollider2D collide;


    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject CubeClone;

    private Button touchbutton;


    void Awake(){
        collide.isTrigger = true;


        touchbutton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("TouchButton").GetComponent<Button> ();

        touchbutton.onClick.AddListener (() => CubeShoot ());



    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
        Instantiate (CubeClone, new Vector3 (0f, 1.934f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }




    public void CubeShoot ()
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("cube").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().isKinematic = false;
    }


}
```

On prefab put the tag: "cube" (Also check if the tag is on the live cube, the one hierarchy)

This should do it.

Comment: but this question collide with only on object

Comment: @ZainKhan can you clarify a doubt? The rigibody of cube is referenced where? I mean. I'm trying to replicate your scene. But in the script "Body" is not being initialised. So when it istantiated, there is no rigidbody referenced on the script.

Comment: I mean, maybe it is missing on Awake: "body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();" on Cube Script

Comment: on CubeScript @ZainKhan

Comment: but the cube rigidbody component is reference in inspector that's why we don't need to put GetComponent and Cube kinematic set to true in Awake function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97135/discussion-between---and-zain-khan).

Comment: could you please help me i'm waiting for your answer and it's a bounty question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355079/audio-doesnt-play-when-instantiate-new-object