# Audio doesn't play when instantiate new object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing audio problems in my project. There are three paddle game objects and one cube. Cube has `Rigidbody2d` or `BoxCollider2d`. And there is also a button script attach to cube which has button function when we click on button cube `Kinematic` becomes false and drop on the paddle. When it's collide with any paddle cube destroy and instantiate again with new prefab. When Cube is falling sound is play and cube is destroy. New cube is instantiate when again click on button then error came.

> `MissingReferenceException`: The object of type `AudioSource` has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

**Scripts on all paddles:**

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource source;
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip hit;
    [SerializeField]
    private BoxCollider2D collide;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject Clone;

    void Awake()
    {
        collide.isTrigger = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
    {
        source.PlayOneShot(hit);
        Destroy(target.gameObject);
        Instantiate(Clone, new Vector3(0f, 4.51f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

**Cube Script:**

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource source;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D body;
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip play;
    private Button bt;
    private float pos;
    public bool check;

    void Start()
    {
        bt = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Button").GetComponent<Button>();
        bt.onClick.AddListener(Fire);
        body.isKinematic = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (check)
        {
            return;
        }

        Vector3 temp = transform.position;
        pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
        temp.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos, -6.25f, 6.25f);
        body.position = temp;
    }

    public void Fire()
    {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Cube>().check = true;
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
        source.PlayOneShot(play);
    }
}
```

**Cube image:**
[image]

**Paddles image:**
[image]

New Export package:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnSXVPdmE5Z3J1SUU

Problem in Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnYzRfVnlQT1FyTlE

Comment: You should show the methods that the button calls, the one creating the new cube. I guess it is calling on the cube and is linked to the old AudioSource that is destroyed with the first cube. You would have to update the reference with the new AudioSource attached on the new Cube.

Comment: @fafase on Cube Script  `public void Fire()` method call on button click and in paddle image i show a clone prefab which add in paddle inspector

Comment: Is it on the same link? Coz that one works just fine again.

Comment: @fafase i edit my question and reuploaded link

Comment: The Reagain package is working just like the previous.

Comment: I did. There is nothing we can do. The only reason why you would get this error could be the fact you are not cleaning the listener like I mentioned already. Have you tried that?

Comment: The reason why you'd have that error is because the Fire method from previous Cube is still register, as a result the listener is trying to access the destroyed AudioSource. So by removing the listener, you prevent the call. Tho, Unity already performs an internal check so dead links are not called, most likely it is creating a memory leak since all items are still referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linked package works fine, it does play the sound every time I launch and destroy a cube.

Nonetheless, you should remove the method on destroy. Unity does not throw any error nor warning when a non-persistent listener is null, kinda weird but this is how it is. You should remove it manually:

```
void OnDestroy(){
    bt.onClick.RemoveListener (Fire);
}
```

But your package does not throw any error when I run it.

Though, I would rethink your approach, instead of the cube assigning its Fire method to the Button event, I would have a script on the button containing the Fire method as well as the AudoiSource and clip. Then on Start, the Cube would pass itself so that the button could access its Cube and Rigidbody2D component.

Best would be to pass a class that contains those are members:

```
public class CubeArgument{
    public readonly Rigidbody2D rg = null;
    public readonly Cube cube = null;  
    public CubeArgument(Rigidbody2D rg, Cube cube){
        this.rg = rg;
        this.cube = cube;
    }
}
```

then here goes your Cube start method:

```
void Start () {
    bt = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Button");
    bt.GetComponent<ButtonController> ().Init(new CubeArgument(body, this));
    body.isKinematic = true;
}
```

The ButtonController reference could even be made static since there is only one for the whole level.

and then on the button you have a ButtonController:

```
public class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour{

     Cube currentCube = null;
     Rigodbody2D currentRig = null;
     public void Init(CubeArgument ca){
         currentRig = ca.rg;
         currentCube = ca.cube;
     }
     public void Fire(){
         if(currentCube != null){ currentCube.check = true; }
         if(currentRig != null) { currentRig.isKinematic = false; }
     }
}
```

Fire is passed as listener to the Button onClick and this is it.

Comment: where i put this `public class CubeArgument{
    public readonly Rigidbody2D rg = null;
    public readonly Cube cube = null;  
    public CubeArgument(Rigidbody2D rg, Cube cube){
        this.rg = rg;
        this.cube = cube;
    }
}` does it's a new script

Comment: I edited, the CubeArgument class is not a component. It is just meant to simplify the passing of argument to the Init method. The class can be put anywhere or on its own script (not within another class).

Comment: hi @zain hard to see what more you could want from an answer than this. is there a chance you could vote it up???

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: OP was using version 5.1.1. This error does not repeat after Unity 5.2.

Tried your package and it is *working fine*!
No errors. Audio played when instantiated.

Are you still facing errors? Weird, dude. Sounds like something is *not clean enough*.
Maybe there is some issue with your build.

**Few things you could try:**

**1-** Try restarting your Unity. Maybe this will force Clean things.

**2-** Create a new project and import your own package to test it!

**3-** I'm using Unity 5.3.0f4 what Unity version are you using? Try an update.

If none of above works, there is something wicked going on with your AudioSource reference and I can't help you with my actual knowledge. But still we can try to do different approaches for that.
Instead of physically referenced it (Dragging and dropping), do it at the start of your script.

**Desperate approach 1**

On Cube.cs:

First remove `[SerializeField]` located above of `private AudioSource source;`  and add the following line on the `Start()` method:

```
source = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
```

Practically the same, but now the script is referencing the own object Audio Source for you. Do the same approach with Paddle.cs. [remember to check the audio name when applying the approach for Paddle script. On paddle the audio name is `PlayOneShot (hit)` not `PlayOneShot (play)`].

If this still trigger some error. Let's try another approach.

**Desperate approach 2**

On Cube.cs:

Remove/Comment the following line on Fire() method:

```
source.PlayOneShot (play);
```

Add the following line to Fire() method:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayOneShot (play);
```

This will get your actual AudioSource on the go. Do the same approach on Paddle.cs [remember to check the audio name when applying the approach for Paddle script. On paddle the audio name is `PlayOneShot (hit)` not `PlayOneShot (play)`].

Comment: i think you all are saying only there are one audio but there are two audios in project first audioclip name is `play` and second is `hit` when click on button `play` sound is produce but when new instantiate cube mean second time when we click then `play` sound not work

Comment: both audios are working here dude. If you notice the code I wrote I even mentioned the both audios. Cause both audio is working. Very weird it is not working for you. :O

Comment: Check my problem in this video......https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnYzRfVnlQT1FyTlE  Also i again export new package  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1H5fdK2PJAnSXVPdmE5Z3J1SUU

Comment: @ZainKhan watched the video. Imported new package. It is working dude. haha it is so weird. haha. Do as mentioned before, create a new project and import your package for test. So weird haha. Both audios working here dude. ALSO: did you tried any of the codes I wrote here?

Comment: when i click second time error came i tried both of your codes

Comment: Very weird. Here work flawlessly. No errors. :O Did you tried any of the code? They might help because they are inside the living object. Try them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98578/discussion-between-zain-khan-and--).

Answer (score 1):

your problem can be from many different places. my guesses:
1)problem with your build: rebuild your code or export all of your package to new project and retest.

2)your target framework: latest version of unity(i have 5.1) just support to  .net 3,5 and unity 4.x supports 2,5 i think. so chek your target framework to not to use functions that is not functional in your version

3)settings of your platform that your editor is running on: it can be volume of your platform to many other settings, first option to know that is run your project on other machine (maybe its a unity bug that part of code is not good for your hardware or driver on platform)

Comment: i uploaded again package